# Finding function $g$ related to given harmonic $ f$ in a certain way

Tags: lie-algebras

I have a harmonic function $f$, so $\Delta(f)=0$. I need to find another scalar function $g$, such that:

1. $\nabla(f)\cdot\nabla(g)=0$ (gradients orthogonal)
2. $\nabla(f) \times \operatorname{Lie}(f,g)= 0$ (so that the Lie derivative of $g$ is either along $\nabla(f)$, $\operatorname{Lie}(f,g) \parallel \nabla(f)$, or $\operatorname{Lie}(f,g)=0$).

For example, in spherical coordinates $\{r,\theta,\phi\}$, if $f=\phi$, then $g=g(r,\theta)$ has $\operatorname{Lie}(f,g) \parallel \nabla(f)$.

Is there a general procedure to find such  $g$ for a given $f$?

Comment: The Lie deeivative of a funtion along a vector field is a function. Do you mean $Lie(f,g)=[\nabla f,\nabla g]$?

Comment: yes, Lie (f,g) = (grad(f).grad) g -  (grad(g).grad) f

Comment: For convenience, denote by $v = \nabla f$ and $w = \nabla g$. You want $v\cdot w = 0$ and $v\wedge [v,w] = 0$. However, note that $\mathcal{L}_v (v\cdot w) = 0$ and hence $[v,v]\cdot w + v \cdot [v,w] = 0 \implies v\cdot [v,w] = 0$. So $v\wedge [v,w] = 0 \implies [v,w] = 0$.

Comment: Willie Wong: Let's have $v=\nabla f$, $w=\nabla g$. I want $v\cdot w=0$ and $v \times ( (v\cdot \nabla) w - (w\cdot \nabla) v) =0$.
Now ${\cal{L}}_v(v \cdot w) \equiv (v\cdot \nabla)  (v \cdot w) =  v \cdot ( (v\cdot \nabla) w + (w\cdot \nabla) v))$, so a plus sign not minus.